# Reading data from a socket in C

Tags: c, sockets

I'm using select to read data from the user and also check for incoming connections. This is my code,

```
 .....
    socket has been created and is listening


        while(1){
            printf("$ ");
            fflush(stdout);
            read_fds = master;

            if(select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1){
                perror(" Select failed: ");
                exit(-1);
            }
            for(int i=0; i <= fdmax; i++){

                if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) {

                    if(i == STDIN){//process user input

                        char usrInputStr[256];
                        if ((rbytes = read(STDIN, usrInputStr, 256)) < 0) {
                            perror("Read error: ");
                            exit(-1);
                        }

                        fgets(usrInputStr, sizeof(usrInputStr), stdin);


                        printf("%s\n",usrInputStr);

 }else if(i == sockServer){//also need to check that this is a server
                    //handle new connection
                    addrlen = sizeof(remoteaddr);
                    sockClient = accept(sockServer, (struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr, &addrlen);
                    if(sockClient < 0){
                        perror("Accept failed: ");
                        exit(-1);
                    }
                    FD_SET(sockClient, &master);
                    if (sockClient > sockServer)
                    {
                        fdmax = sockClient;
                    }

                }
```

The code doesn't print the user input back on the I/O. Can't seem to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: Did you use a debugger? It seems like you've got more work to do on your end before you ask for help. Throwing an incomplete block of code with the statement "it's broken, why?" at random people is not very productive.

Comment: `STDIN` should be `STDIN_FILENO`.

Answer (score 0):

Three obvious things jump out:

1. `if (sockClient > sockServer)` should probably be `if (sockClient > fdmax)`.
2. You read from stdin twice, one with `read` (which is good) and once with `fgets` (which is bad).
3. ```
                   printf("%s\n",usrInputStr);
   ```

   The `%s` format specifier is for C-style strings, not arbitrary arrays of characters. You didn't do anything with `rbytes`, so how could it possibly know how many characters to print?